# How to compile static library from enormous amount .c and .h files in MS VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, static-libraries, fltk

I am learning how to compile libraries and want to compile the fltk library for example.
To compile a static library I need .h and .c files and just compile them, but the library has not only many .h and .c files, but some other files I don't know what to do with them. In a folder called "src" with .c files there are some .h files, .xbm, .xpm, .fl and etc. including "Makefile" that maybe can help me I suppose.

So, how to do it right?

Comment: From looking at the source code for FLTK (https://github.com/fltk/test-only/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) I see that FLTK  uses `CMake` to build. Using `CMake` you can generate a Visual Studio project file for whatever version of Visual Studio you have.

Comment: Thanks. It somehow worked. Cmake generated a VS solution that contains projects for every the library module, then I compiled it. 72 succeeded,  11 failed ,2 skipped. VS did some .lib files including fltk.lib. fltk.lib worked for an example of using the fltk library.
Don't know what does it mean. It's like worked but...

Answer (score 3):

How about using the build system that came with the library?

Sounds like it's expecting you to run `make`.

But even if it was using something else, like CMake or SCons, it still seems like the best option would be to just use what it expects rather than trying to import it into some other build system.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not an answer but a question/comment. Consider moving it into comments' section instead.